# Extend D3 Chart to add tooltip from HTML page

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a D3 graph showing tooltip on mouseover. The graph is currently created from a JS file.

D3 graph code:

```
var tooltip = d3.select('body')
  .append('div')
  .style('position', 'absolute')
  .style('padding', '0 10px')
  .style('background', 'white')
  .style('opacity', 0);

var svgE = svg
   .append("g")
  .selectAll()
  .data(graph.data)
  .join("rect")
  .attr("x", xFunc)
  .attr("y", yFunc)
  .on('mouseover', function (d) {
      tooltip.transition().duration(200)
          .style('opacity', .9);
      var toolTipText = d.x + " - " + d.y;
      tooltip.html(toolTipText)
          .style('left', (d3.event.pageX - 35) + 'px')
          .style('top', (d3.event.pageY - 30) + 'px');
  })
  .on('mouseout', function (d) {
      tooltip.transition().duration(200)
          .style('opacity', 0);
      tooltip.html("");
  });
```

Is it possible to remove the tooltip code from the JS file and move it to an HTML page so I can add tooltip functionality whenever needed?

D3 code in JS file will be:

```
var svgE = svg
  .append("g")
  .selectAll()
  .data(graph.data)
  .join("rect")
  .attr("x", xFunc)
  .attr("y", yFunc);
```

What do I add in the HTML  block to add tooltip functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example you provided creates a tooltip entirely in JavaScript, but if you for whatever reason prefer creating a tooltip in HTML you can do that as well.

```js
const mainSvg = d3.select('svg#mainSvg');
const tooltip = d3.select('div.tooltip');

const aRectangle = mainSvg.append('rect')
  .attr('x', 50)
  .attr('y', 50)
  .attr('height', 100)
  .attr('width', 100)
  .attr('fill', 'green');

  aRectangle.on('mouseover', (d) => {
    tooltip.style('visibility', 'visible');
    tooltip.html('You are mousing over a rectangle.');
    tooltip.style('left', `${d3.event.pageX}px`)
      .style('top', `${d3.event.pageY}px`)
  });

  aRectangle.on('mouseout', (d) => {
      tooltip.style('visibility', 'hidden');
  });
```

```css
svg#mainSvg {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: gray;
}

div.tooltip {
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  pointer-events: none;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <svg id='mainSvg'></svg>
</div>

<div class='tooltip'>
  This is a tooltip
</div>
```